# Валидация формы на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Не работает этот код:

```
formWriteUs.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  if (!loginWriteUs.value || !emailWriteUs.value) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("Нужно ввести имя и мейл!");
  }
});
```

Не понимаю почему(

```js
// Открытие модального окна "Напишите нам"
var buttonWriteUs = document.querySelector(".js-button-write-us");
var modalWriteUs = document.querySelector(".js-modal-write-us");
var buttonCloseWriteUs = modalWriteUs.querySelector(".modal-close");
var formWriteUs = modalWriteUs.querySelector("form");
var loginWriteUs = modalWriteUs.querySelector("#name-surname");
var emailWriteUs = modalWriteUs.querySelector("#email");

buttonWriteUs.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  modalWriteUs.classList.add('js-modal__show');
  loginWriteUs.focus();
});

buttonCloseWriteUs.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  modalWriteUs.classList.remove('js-modal__show');
});

formWriteUs.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  if (!loginWriteUs.value || !emailWriteUs.value) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("Нужно ввести имя и мейл!");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="modal-wrapper js-modal-write-us">
  <section class="modal modal-write-us">
    <h2 class="visually-hidden">Напишите нам...</h2>
    <form class="form-write-us" action="https://echo.htmlacademy.ru" method="post">
      <p class="form-write-us__item name-field">
        <label for="name-surname">Ваше имя:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name-surname" id="name-surname" placeholder="Имя Фамилия" required>
      </p>
      <p class="form-write-us__item email-field">
        <label for="email">Ваш e-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email@example.com" required>
      </p>

      <p class="form-write-us__item comment-field">
        <label for="comment">Текст письма:</label>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="В свободной форме"></textarea>
      </p>
      <button class="button button-form" type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
    <button class="modal-close" type="button"><span class="visually-hidden">Закрыть</span></button>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно отключить валидацию формы перед сабмитом. Для этого добавьте атрибут novalidate к форме.

```js
// Открытие модального окна "Напишите нам"
var buttonWriteUs = document.querySelector(".js-button-write-us");
var modalWriteUs = document.querySelector(".js-modal-write-us");
var buttonCloseWriteUs = modalWriteUs.querySelector(".modal-close");
var formWriteUs = modalWriteUs.querySelector("form");
var loginWriteUs = modalWriteUs.querySelector("#name-surname");
var emailWriteUs = modalWriteUs.querySelector("#email");


buttonCloseWriteUs.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  modalWriteUs.classList.remove('js-modal__show');
});

formWriteUs.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  if (!loginWriteUs.value || !emailWriteUs.value) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("Нужно ввести имя и мейл!");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="modal-wrapper js-modal-write-us">
  <section class="modal modal-write-us">
    <h2 class="visually-hidden">Напишите нам...</h2> 
    <form class="form-write-us" action="https://echo.htmlacademy.ru" method="post" novalidate>
      <p class="form-write-us__item name-field">
        <label for="name-surname">Ваше имя:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name-surname" id="name-surname" placeholder="Имя Фамилия" required>
      </p>
      <p class="form-write-us__item email-field">
        <label for="email">Ваш e-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email@example.com" required>
      </p>

      <p class="form-write-us__item comment-field">
        <label for="comment">Текст письма:</label>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="В свободной форме"></textarea>
      </p>
      <button class="button button-form" type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
    <button class="modal-close" type="button"><span class="visually-hidden">Закрыть</span></button>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Это кнопка открытия модального окна этой формы.

Comment: @СтаниславКремса обновил ответ

Comment: все верно, заработало, поставил вам плюсик и отметил галочкой)